# $a^{(m+n)}_{ij} \geq a^{(m)}_{ik}a^{(n)}_{kl}$ for non-negative Matrix $A$

Tags: matrices, induction, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be a non-negative infinite Matrix (all entries $\geq 0$). $a_{ij}^{(n)}$ denotes the $ij$-th entry of $A^n$.
Does the following inequality hold:
$a^{(m+n)}_{ij} \geq a^{(m)}_{ik}a^{(n)}_{kl},\forall i,j,k,\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

We clearly have $a^{(2)}_{ij} \geq a^{(1)}_{ik}a^{(1)}_{kj},\forall i,k,j$. Can the rest be shown by a induction argument or how to make it precise?

Comment: @GitGud Sorry, added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, every entry is positive,
$$
a_{ij}^{(n+m)} = \sum_{k=1}^d a_{ik}^{(m)} a_{kj}^{(n)} 
\ge a_{ik_0}^{(m)} a_{k_0j}^{(n)} 
$$for each $k_0$. Otherwise there is no reason.

Comment: I do not know about Markov chains (I guess it is not related to the statement about the matrix?). But written like this it is actually rather obvious. I missed the simple fact to use associativity of matrix multiplication to obtain the sum term for any values of $n$ and $m$.

Comment: the $a_{ij}^{(n)}$ is a typical Markov chains notation ;) I'm happy if I could help you.